# Does Kevin Uxbridge use the turbolift?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Near the end of “The Survivors,” the Douwd (Kevin Uxbridge) vanishes out of sight after its non-human nature is revealed by Captain Picard. Geordi then remarks that it is in the turbolift.

Does this mean that the Douwd actually rode the turbolift enroute to Deanna’s quarters? What an odd picture that would be!

It’s possible, of course, that the Douwd passed through the wall of the lift in its energy form. Obviously there is no answer in the episode itself, but does any other source speak to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I'll speculate, but I'm happy to be proven wrong by actual evidence)*

When we see the Douwd in Troi's quarters, he is again in human form as Kevin Uxbridge. At some point between the bridge and her quarters, he must have decided to return to his human form. I think this is because he's grown attached to that form as a result of his relationship with Rishon.

If I'm right, he would have intended to return to human form *as soon as possible*, and it would be logical for him to transform into energy just long enough to enter the turbolift. He would then be able to travel the rest of the way as his human, Kevin Uxbridge, persona.

Comment: This is as good an answer as any. I checked [the transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/151.htm) and there are no further clues about it.

Comment: I'd agree that he seems to be very comfortable and 'at home' as Kevin Uxbridge so would return to this form as soon as he's able.